# Solidity: substitute for returns (strings[])

Tags: solidity, mapping, string

I have a mapping

```
mapping (address => string[]) myMap;
```

How can I return the list of all the strings associated to a given address?

I know that in Solidity one can't return an array of strings, but what I would need to do is like

```
function get(address _addr) public returns (string[]){
       return myMap[_addr];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to do this if you change the string for bytes32 and make the array fixed in length. For instance, for an array of 10 elements.

```
mapping (address => bytes32[10]) myMap;
function get(address _addr) public returns (bytes32[10]){
   return myMap[_addr];
}
```

The issue is that you will need to encode your string as bytes32.

Another option is to activate the experimental ABI encoder in solidity using:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

    contract mycontract{

        mapping (address => string[]) myMap;

        function get(address _addr) public returns (string[]){
           return myMap[_addr];
        }

    }
```

This is experimental and is not recommended for production.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How can I limit the size of the string array? In my case, I have that the string array contains fixed length strings (of 32 bytes). Thank you again

Comment: I am sorry, my answer on the string was incorrect, I updated it, take a look and let me know.